# AWS how to handle programatic credentilas when building a docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, terraform, amazon-ecs

I have a .net core app in which I'm using services such as S3, RDS and Dynamo. Initially every instance of a client was initilaized using the Access_KEY and Secret_Access_Key direrectly, so basically these two were stored in a configuration file. Recently we've started a process to automate the AWS infrastructure creating using Terraform we are trying to migrate from manged container (Fargate and Amplify) to ECS, and we've also migrated from using plain secrets to using profiles.

In windows I've installed AWS CLI to configure a profile and under my

> Users/{myUser/.aws

the following two files were creatd : config and credentials.

But how to configure a profile when using docker on linux I don't exactly know what are the steps that I should follow. When creating a CI-CD pipeline where after a commit and a successful build of a docker image, a new container should pop into existing replacing the old one. Should i configure the aws profile within the docker container running the app ? Should I generate a new set of Keys everytime a new container is build and replaces the old one ? The way this approach sounds, I don't belive this is the way to do it, but have no idea how to actually do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using profiles when running inside AWS. Profiles are great for running the code locally, but when your code is deployed on ECS it should be utilizing a [task IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html).

You would manage that in Terraform by creating the IAM role, and then assigning the role to the task in the ECS task definition.

Comment: ok, is this going to impact the way the code is written ?

Comment: You should really read [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html#net-dg-config-creds-assign-profile) in the documentation before continuing further. At this point I'm just repeating sections of that page to you here.